# Find the Fourier transform of exponential of two variables?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I have this function of two variables $x$ and $y$:
$$
\exp(-2 \pi^2 \sigma^2 (u^2 + v^2))
$$
How can I compute the Fourier transform of this? I know what to do for the case of only one variable. In that case, we have
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\exp(-2 \pi^2 \sigma^2 x^2)\}
(u) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp(-\frac{u^2}{2 \sigma^2})
$$
but I cannot get my head around how to compute it for two variables. Can someone help me out? Would be much appreciated.

Bonus info: I am attempting to derive the Fourier transform of a 2D Gaussian :)
$$
G(x, y, \sigma) = G(x, \sigma) * G(y, \sigma)
$$

Comment: Hint : $e^{a+b} = e^a \,e^b$

Comment: @LL3.14 I know -- but what I don't know is how to apply it to solve this :p

Comment: Hint 2 then: the Fourier transform of the tensor product is the tensor product of the Fourier transforms ...

Comment: @LL3.14 Tensor product?

Comment: $(f\otimes g)(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$

Comment: You have two variables $x$ and $y$. To make a Fourier transform, the result will depend on two variables $u$ and $v$

Comment: @Andrei I am aware of that - not my intension if I indicated otherwise. My example for a Fourier transform was the case of 1 variable while my goal is to compute it for 2 variables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular case it's relatively simple, since we can split the 2D Gaussian into a product of two Gaussians:$$
\mathcal{F}\{\exp(-2 \pi^2 \sigma^2 (x^2+y^2))\}
(u,v) = \mathcal{F}\{\exp(-2 \pi^2 \sigma^2 x^2)\}
(u)\cdot \mathcal{F}\{\exp(-2 \pi^2 \sigma^2 y^2)\}
(v)\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp(-\frac{u^2}{2 \sigma^2})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp(-\frac{v^2}{2 \sigma^2})\\=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2} \exp(-\frac{u^2+v^2}{2 \sigma^2})
$$
I suggest you look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_transform), in particular the section about separability of the Fourier Transform.

Comment: Separability of the Fourier transform -- that's it!! Thanks man. Much love

Comment: We can use the separability property of the Fourier transform only because the 2D Gaussian can be written as product of 2 1D Gaussians or what do you mean by your first sentence?

Comment: Yes. If you can't write it as a product you will need to calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy e^{iux}e^{ivy}f(x,y)$$